# Using batch to recursively update documents only works on small collection

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I have a collection of teams containing around 80 000 documents. Every Monday I would like to reset the scores of every team using firebase cloud functions. This is my function:

```
exports.resetOrgScore = functions.runWith(runtimeOpts).pubsub.schedule("every monday 00:00").timeZone("Europe/Oslo").onRun(async (context) => {

let batch = admin.firestore().batch();
let count = 0;
let overallCount = 0;
const orgDocs = await admin.firestore().collection("teams").get();
orgDocs.forEach(async(doc) => {
    batch.update(doc.ref, {score:0.0});
    if (++count >= 500 || ++overallCount >= orgDocs.docs.length) {
      await batch.commit();
      batch = admin.firestore().batch();
      count = 0;
    }
});
```

});

I tried running the function in a smaller collection of 10 documents and it's working fine, but when running the function in the "teams" collection it returns "Cannot modify a WriteBatch that has been committed". I tried returning the promise like this(code below) but that doesn't fix the problem. Thanks in advance :)

```
return await batch.commit().then(function () {
            batch = admin.firestore().batch();
            count = 0;
            return null;
          });
```

Comment: If you change to `++count >= 250`, does that make a difference?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen thanks for your suggestion, but I still get the same error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are three problems in your code:

1. You use `async/await` with `forEach()` which is not recommended: The problem is that the  callback passed to `forEach()` is not being awaited, see more explanations [here](https://www.hacksparrow.com/javascript/foreach-in-promise-async-function.html) or [here](https://codeburst.io/javascript-async-await-with-foreach-b6ba62bbf404).
2. As detailed in the error you "Cannot modify a WriteBatch that has been committed". With `await batch.commit(); batch = admin.firestore().batch();` it's exactly what you are doing.
3. As important, you don't return the promise returned by the asynchronous methods. See [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/terminate-functions) for more details.

You'll find in the [doc](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/delete-data#collections) (see Node.js tab) a code which allows to delete, by recursively using a batch, all the docs of a collection. It's easy to adapt it to update the docs, as follows. Note that we use a `dateUpdated` flag to select the docs for each new batch: with the original code, the docs were deleted so no need for a flag...

```
const runtimeOpts = {
    timeoutSeconds: 540,
    memory: '1GB',
};

exports.resetOrgScore = functions
     .runWith(runtimeOpts)
     .pubsub
     .schedule("every monday 00:00")
     .timeZone("Europe/Oslo")
     .onRun((context) => {

        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            deleteQueryBatch(resolve).catch(reject);
        });
     
      });

async function deleteQueryBatch(resolve) {
    const db = admin.firestore();
    const snapshot = await db
        .collection('teams')
        .where('dateUpdated', '==', "20210302")
        .orderBy('__name__')
        .limit(499)
        .get();

    const batchSize = snapshot.size;
    if (batchSize === 0) {
        // When there are no documents left, we are done
        resolve();
        return;
    }

    // Delete documents in a batch
    const batch = db.batch();
    snapshot.docs.forEach((doc) => {
        batch.update(doc.ref, { score:0.0, dateUpdated:  "20210303" });
    });
    await batch.commit();

    // Recurse on the next process tick, to avoid
    // exploding the stack.
    process.nextTick(() => {
        deleteQueryBatch(resolve);
    });
}
```

Note that the above Cloud Function is [**configured with the maximum value**](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/manage-functions#set_timeout_and_memory_allocation) for the time out, i.e. 9 minutes.

If it appears that all your docs cannot be updated within 9 minutes, you will need to find another approach, for example using the Admin SDK from one of your server, or cutting the work into pieces and run the CF several times.